# SQL Date Query: Is 'not equal' more expensive than 'less than'

Tags: sql-server

On a date field I have a default value that indicates a non-completion of a task.
When I query to find all completed tasks which is better if my default date is 12/31/9999?

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Completed  <> '12/31/9999'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Completed  < '12/31/9999'
```

Or does it completely depend on my indexing.

Comment: If there is no completion date would it not make more semantic sense to use a NULL?

Comment: Is this the first documented Y10K bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the key operators used in the WHERE clause, ordered by their performance. Those operators at the top will produce results faster than those listed at the bottom.

```
 =
>, >=, <, <=
LIKE
<>
```

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/t-sql-where/

Comment: The placement of `LIKE` on that list seems somewhat arbitrary. It can go either at the top with `=` (if no wild cards) or bottom (if leading wildcard)

Comment: Thanks, This looks like a good general rule to apply.  Since I'm not a dba.

Answer (score 1):

Not much difference probably.

If an index on `Completed` is used to satisfy the query then the `<>` will be two range seeks (`< '12/31/9999'` and `> '12/31/9999'`) rather than just the `<` seek.

So best to use `<` to avoid the unnecessary additional `>` seek that doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me understand the seeking aspect of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your problem very well but this kind of comparison depends exclusively on your indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> On a date field I have a default value that indicates a non-completion of a task

It makes more sense for that field to be nullable and make the default value to be null. So, the absense of a date in that field means the task has not been completed.

You can easily solve this by altering your table and set the default value to null and also by updating all values where compeleted = '12/31/9999' to null. Then, the query you would run would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Completed IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Just as an aside to this.  I've seen a few databases that decide to store the dates as zero instead of null.  Try to avoid that practice cause it can cause real problems with querying later on.  Just leave them as null.